# Rails 4: validate maximum value of integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In Rails 4, how can you add a model validation for a maximum value on an integer column?

For example, I want to add a validation to the column "age", to have a maximum value of 100.

There are many questions with answers for Rails 3 and earlier. The [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#inclusion) do not mention any way of checking integer values.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Take a look at the [numericality](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#numericality) validators.

In your case, something like

`validates :age, numericality: { less_than_or_equal_to: 100,  only_integer: true }`